# Best way to append params to url without function

Tags: javascript

i am looking to find the best way to keep adding a id to the url params example.

```
http://example.com/1
```

so say if i had it set around a interval it would be.

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {

document.location.search = 'http://example.com/' + i++;

}, 1000);
```

what i am trying to result is the extra param to the url without a page refresh so it would just keep updating.

```
http://example.com/1
http://example.com/2
http://example.com/3
http://example.com/4
```

etc...

any help please.

Comment: Instead of `document.location.search`, have you already tried `document.title`? The *search property* returns the query portion of a URL. If yes, whats wrong with your code? Which error is returning?

Comment: This sounds like a bad solution to a problem. Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this. one is to use HTML5 [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) , will be this code :

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {

history.pushState(null, document.title, 'example.com/' + i++);

}, 1000);
```

However, this will push it to the browser history and not all browsers support it. If I remember correctly there's a way to push it to url without pushing it to history, but read a bit about it to see if you can do it.

Or you can use hash codes in case you don't mind a little `#` over there, but it will probably annoy the visitor as it might bump the page to top every second, if you don't mind then this is your code :

```
var i = 0;
var url= window.location.href;
setInterval(function() {

window.location.href = url+"#"+i++;


}, 1000);
```

However this sounds like a bad idea anyway, so reconsider using it. I'm pretty sure what you're trying to achive can be done in a cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks yes i agree its not the best but the client wants the url to reference the slider image for sharing...

Comment: Why not on click on the share button take the id of the selected slider image and add it to the url via get parameter or any other type so you'll know to return to it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the "[fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)" which is the part of the url that can be changed without a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really sound logical but if you really need to do this you could use [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

simplest way to achieve this would be:

```
history.pushState("", "", "/1");
```

do take note that [support in IE is very limited](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate)

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done in Chrome, Safari, FF,  IE10.

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

In your case:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {

window.history.pushState(“”, “”,'http://example.com/' + i++);

}, 1000);
```

More information here:

http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/